# How can I add animation to pop back stack?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm creating a Kotlin app. How can I set exit or enter animation to pop back stack with navigation component? My code:
`navHostFragment.findNavController().popBackStack()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add animation with using navigation xml file like this.

```
 <action
        android:id="@+id/something"
        app:destination="@id/destionation_fragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
```

Here an example of animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="true">
<translate
    android:duration="@integer/medior_anim_time"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

You can add whatever animation you want.

Comment: I know how to use animations. I need animation on pop back stack.

Comment: When you add animation to navigation like the first code part I suggest you can see it automatically animated on pop back stack. That is how you animate on navigation transactions.

Answer (score 0):

My fragment transaction method looks like this,

```
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(anim.fade_in, anim.fade_out,anim.fade_in, anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(id.framelayout1, fragment, tag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I have set custom animations using

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(anim.fade_in, anim.fade_out,anim.fade_in, anim.fade_out);
```

You can see that I have used the same In and Out animation twice.

Code can run with one In and out animation pair. But when we pop to the back stack it doesn't give any animation.

When we use the same animation pair again it is assigned as (popEnter, popExit).

Then it gives animations on popBackStack. You can use other animation pair If you want.

Tested and supported on API 33.